# Update context menu of all file extensions in Windows via powershell takes long time

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

Developing our own application for our company only, we have developed script used for installation from shared drive. Except the installation itself, the script should also create/update values in the registry of particular user (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`).

These values are separated for:

- Directories (`HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory`)
- All File Extensions (`HKCU:\Software\Classes\*`)

For the directory folder the update is immediate, where for the extensions it seems to take quite some time depending on machine hardware (from 40 sec to 2 minutes).

Now there is a trouble to create "entry" in the registry for the folder named `*` only. I've got a question for this to resolve ([PowerShell: How do I create selector on file/folder, whose name is '*' (asterisk/star)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48786037/7167572)).

Ignoring the issue above, we have found some solution how the `string path` works, however I'm not sure what is happening behind the code and do not understand why it takes so long time.

```
# Directory
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\classes\Directory" -Name "shell" | Out-Null
# All Files Extension
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\classes\[*]" -Name "shell" | Out-Null
```

One idea is that the `[*]` solution actually goes through all the file extensions, but the registry itself is showing this `NewItem` under `*` folder and not shown under particular extensions:

[image: Registry screenshot]

Another idea about this, is when we have a registry file (`*.reg`), by running the file the registry entry is added immediately and resolve the case.

---

**Questions:**

- What is actually happening when we are running the query to add entry under `[*]` selector?
- How can be this process optimized to lower the time for creating new folder in registry for all files' extension?

Comment: If you remove the `| Out-Null` redirection you'll get more information about what the command is doing.

Comment: @gvee Thx, I tried do so however the output does not helped at all (just shown the correct path) and calling `New-Item` or `Set-ItemProperty` on the folder takes same long amount of time.

Comment: Ok, well consider performing a `Set-Location -Path "HKCU:\Software\classes\"` before simpler, `-Name` only `New-Item` call

Comment: @gvee Please create an answer, for me `New-Item` is faster using `Set-Location -literalPath <pathWithAsterisk>`. For the `New-ItemProperty` we can use param `-literalPath` which does the work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* what's happening is that the `-Path` in your `New-Item` call is recursive because of the wildcard. Hence the delay.

Here's a workaround to the issue:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath "HKCU:\Software\classes\*"
New-Item -Name "shell"
```

`New-Item` uses the *current location* as the `-Path` if not explicitly passed to the function.